# Nginx with postfix not sending mail - from address appearing wrong

Tags: nginx, postfix

I am using a php form to send email. The script reports success, but the mail never arrives.

The tail of the mail log shows:

```
Nov 22 01:24:25 contra postfix/pickup[1195]: 0CC1B119A53: uid=100 from=<nginx>
Nov 22 01:24:25 contra postfix/cleanup[1320]: 0CC1B119A53: message-id=<20111122012425.0CC1B119A53@contra.net.au>
Nov 22 01:24:25 contra postfix/qmgr[1196]: 0CC1B119A53: from=<nginx@myhostname.myhostname>, size=363, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Just wondering where this from address is coming from and if thats why mails aren't arriving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nginx@myhostname.myhostname` comes from the fact that your nginx is running under the user account named `nginx` (userid 100) on your host `myhostname.myhostname`. So nothing special and just normal.